# C read txt file, save information in struct and call with a function

Tags: c

I am fairly new to C and i have some questions. The task was to read the input.txt file and to first determine the number of lines (which i succesfully did). However the next task is to read the file line by line and to save each lines information into a struct. As you can see the task is also focused on creating as many functions as possible and that is where i am struggling right now. However i only want help with the "void readInputData" part. If someone could explain to me where my mistake is (why nothing is being printed) and maybe explain how to call the function properly in the main function that would be great. the output file wasnt part of the task i created it for myself to find some errors.

```
Input.txt : 
1. M 17 160 13.24
2. M 18 177 13.22
3. M 15 162 14.78
4. F 16 169 15.55
5. F 16 161 14.73
6. F 16 160 10.80
7. M 14 192 15.65
8. F 18 197 12.41
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int iNumberOfLines = 1;


typedef struct {
char ignore[2];
char Gender;
int Age;
int Height;
float Time;
} Student_t;

Student_t *pStudents;

int determineNumberOfLines(FILE *pInputFile);
void readInputData(FILE *pInputFile, FILE *output, int iNumberOfLines, Student_t *pStudents);

// void calculateAverages(double *dAvHeight, double *dAvAge, double *dAvTime, Student_t *pStudents, int iNumberOfLines);

// Student_t* searchFastest(Student_t *pStudents, int iNumberOfLines);

// void printToConsole(Student_t *pFastestStudent, double dAvHeight, double dAvAge, double dAvTime);



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *pInputFile = fopen ("resources/Input.txt", "r");
    if (pInputFile == NULL){
        printf("Fehler beim Öffnen");
        return -1;
    }
    FILE *output = fopen ("resources/Output.txt", "w");
    if (output == NULL){
        printf("Fehler beim Öffnen");
        return -1;
    }


    printf("LINES: %d\n",determineNumberOfLines(pInputFile));
    Student_t *pStudents;

    readInputData(pInputFile, output, iNumberOfLines, pStudents);

    return 0;

}

int determineNumberOfLines(FILE *pInputFile){
    int ch;
    while(!feof(pInputFile))
    {
      ch = fgetc(pInputFile);
      if(ch == '\n')
      {
          iNumberOfLines++;
      }
    }

    return iNumberOfLines;
    fclose(pInputFile);
}

void readInputData(FILE *pInputFile, FILE *output, int iNumberOfLines, Student_t *pStudents){
int i = 0;
char buffer [120];




while (fgets(buffer, 120, pInputFile) != 0) //ließt zeile und speichert in "buffer" als string
{

 if (sscanf(buffer, "%2[^.]. %c %d %d %.2f", &pStudents[i].ignore, &pStudents[i].Gender, &pStudents[i].Age, &pStudents[i].Height, &pStudents[i].Time) !=1)
        {
 printf("%d",&pStudents[i].Age);
     fprintf(output,"%c",pStudents[i].Gender);
             i++;
        }

}
fclose(pInputFile);
fclose(output);

}
```

Thanks in advance !

**UPDATE !!!**

I am now having trouble with the next function

```
void calculateAverages(double *dAvHeight, double *dAvAge, double *dAvTime, Student_t *pStudents, int iNumberOfLines);
```

I can only define `dAvHeight dAvAge dAvTime` as Ints, however later on i need to change them to float to calculate averages. Can anyone explain how i do that while keep using `dAvHeight dAvAge dAvTime`.

Thanks again

Here is the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



int iNumberOfLines = 1;
int dAvHeight = 0, dAvAge = 0, dAvTime = 0;




typedef struct {
int ignore;
char Gender;
int Age;
int Height;
float Time;
} Student_t;



int determineNumberOfLines(FILE *pInputFile);
void readInputData(FILE *pInputFile,  int iNumberOfLines, Student_t *pStudents);
void calculateAverages(double *dAvHeight, double *dAvAge, double *dAvTime, Student_t *pStudents, int iNumberOfLines);
// Student_t* searchFastest(Student_t *pStudents, int iNumberOfLines);

// void printToConsole(Student_t *pFastestStudent, double dAvHeight, double dAvAge, double dAvTime);



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    FILE *pInputFile = fopen ("resources/Input.txt", "r");
    if (pInputFile == NULL){
            printf("Fehler beim Öffnen");
            return -1;
        }
    determineNumberOfLines(pInputFile);
    //printf("LINES: %d\n",determineNumberOfLines(pInputFile));
    Student_t pStudents[iNumberOfLines];
    //printf("%d", iNumberOfLines);
    readInputData(pInputFile, iNumberOfLines, pStudents);

    calculateAverages(dAvHeight, dAvAge, dAvTime, pStudents, iNumberOfLines);

    return 0;

}

int determineNumberOfLines(FILE *pInputFile){

fopen ("resources/Input.txt", "r");
    int ch;
    while(!feof(pInputFile))
    {
      ch = fgetc(pInputFile);
      if(ch == '\n')
      {
          iNumberOfLines++;
      }
    }

    fclose(pInputFile);
    return iNumberOfLines;

}

void readInputData(FILE *pInputFile, int iNumberOfLines, Student_t *pStudents){

fopen ("resources/Input.txt", "r");

int i = 0;
char buffer [120];



while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pInputFile) != 0)
{

 if (sscanf(buffer, "%d. %c %d %d %f", &pStudents[i].ignore, &pStudents[i].Gender, &pStudents[i].Age, &pStudents[i].Height, &pStudents[i].Time) <= sizeof buffer)
        {
             i++;
        }

}
fclose(pInputFile);
}

void calculateAverages(double *dAvHeight, double *dAvAge, double *dAvTime, Student_t *pStudents, int iNumberOfLines){
    int i;
    int sumHeight = 0;
    int sumAge = 0;
    float sumTime = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= (iNumberOfLines-1); i++){
        sumHeight = sumHeight + pStudents[i].Height;
    }
    dAvHeight = sumHeight/ iNumberOfLines;
    printf("Average Height is = %.2f \n", dAvHeight);


    for (i = 0; i<= (iNumberOfLines-1); i++){
        sumAge = sumAge + pStudents[i].Age;
    }
    //dAvAge = sumAge/iNumberOfLines;
    printf("Average Age is = %.2f \n", dAvAge);


    for (i = 0; i<= (iNumberOfLines-1); i++){
        sumTime = sumTime + pStudents[i].Time;
    }
    //dAvTime = sumTime/iNumberOfLines;
    printf("Average Time is = %.2f \n", dAvTime);
}
```

Comment: After calling `determineNumberOfLines` the file stream is at the end of the file. So of course you won't be able to successfully read anything in `readInputData` unless you first call `rewind` or `fclose/fopen` to start back at the beginning of the file.

Comment: `return iNumberOfLines; fclose(pInputFile);` That code doesn't make sense. The function exits when `return` is called. Any code after the `return` will never run.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks !  So swapping return and fclose would help right?

Comment: Sort of. But then you would be missing an `fopen` before `readInputData`. Better to call `rewind`.

Comment: As our teacher hasnt really taught us rewind (yet) i would like to avoid using it, if i add fopen in the start of every function and fclose in the end, would that work? Is that something i have to always do in functions (re-opening the file)?

Comment: Yes that will work. But it's nothing to do with functions. It would be the same even if you didn't use functions. Each read/write operation (e.g `fgetc`) moves the file stream location forward. If you want to read/write somewhere that isn't the current file location then you need to do something to move the location back to where you want to read from.

Comment: Okay good to know thanks, but I still have the issue that nothing is being printed from the readInputData Function.

Comment: _liest_ is not spelled with sharp s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> nothing is being printed from the readInputData Function

You try to read something into memory pointed to by the uninitialized `Student_t *pStudents`. After you correctly determined `iNumberOfLines`, you can define `Student_t pStudents[iNumberOfLines];` instead.

Comment: Yesss that helped tremendously, Stuff is finally getting printed. However its nonsense that is being printed and i suspect this -> "%2[^.]. %c %d %d %.2f"  to be the cause.... NVM found my error  i changed char ignore to int ignore and changed the sscan section to "%d. %c %d %d %.2f"

Comment: Everything works perfectly now thank you kaylum and Armali

Comment: Fine - then I assume you noticed that from `printf("%d",&pStudents[i].Age);` you had to remove the `&`.